# Indexing a numpy array with a numpy array of indexes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a 3D numpy array `data` and another array `pos` of indexes (an index is a numpy array on its own, which makes the latter array a 2D array):

```
import numpy as np
data = np.arange(8).reshape(2, 2, -1)
#array([[[0, 1],
#    [2, 3]],
#
#  [[4, 5],
#    [6, 7]]])

pos = np.array([[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]])
#array([[1, 1, 0],
#       [0, 1, 0],
#       [1, 0, 0]])
```

I want to select and/or mutate the elements from `data` using the indexes from `pos`. I can do the selection using a `for` loop or a list comprehension:

```
[data[tuple(i)] for i in pos]
#[6, 2, 4]
data[[i for i in pos.T]]
#array([6, 2, 4])
```

But this does not seem to be a numpy way. Is there a vectorized numpy solution to this problem?

Comment: Do you care if the method returns a view vs a copy?

Comment: Not technically an exact dupe.  But all relevant info is there.  Let me know if you want it reopened.

Comment: If you're not satisfied with the answer or the dupe, ping either one of us here. We'll be happy to reopen and slap a bounty on this to incentivise someone smarter to come up with a solution that doesn't exist yet ;-)

Comment: @piRSquared Found an exact dupe.

Comment: @Divakar thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split `pos` into 3 separate arrays and index, like so—

```
>>> i, j, k = pos.T
>>> data[i, j, k]
array([6, 2, 4])
```

Here, the number of columns in `pos` correspond to the depth of `data`. As long as you're dealing with 3D matrices, getting `i`, `j`, and `k` well never get more complicated than this.

On python-3.6+, you can shorten this to—

```
>>> data[[*pos.T]]
array([6, 2, 4])
```

Comment: Ouch, downvoter please let me know if there's anything semantically wrong with this answer (from what I can tell, this gives OP what they're expecting). I'd like to correct it! Thanks.

Comment: In a sense, you are doing `[i for i in pos.T]`, except that your solution works only for 3 items. My concern is that the list comprehension seems unnecessary here. Isn't there a native numpy way to reorganize the array?

Comment: @DyZ I added an explanation. If you want to index more items, you will have more rows, not columns. The columns correspond to the depth; and as long as you're dealing with 3D arrays, getting i, j, and k will be done the same way. This will work for 3 items, and it will work for many more.

Comment: tensorflow has tf.gather_nd. Is there not an analog to numpy?

Comment: @MFisherKDX Tensorflow is built on top of numpy. It likely does something like this under the hood. But I'll keep looking. This is the most straightforward solution I am aware of :)

Comment: @MFisherKDX In fact, gather is what I want. I thought `np.take` would work, but it does not seem to support nd arrays.

Comment: Yeah. I downvoted this answer and started to post my own using take and then realized it didn't work and removed my downvote. Sorry Coldspeed

Comment: @MFisherKDX Well, if OP doesn't mind a python-3.6 solution, I've added it.

Comment: `data[[*pos.T]]` is deprecated since [v1.15.0](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/releases/tag/v1.15.0): "Multidimensional indexing with anything but a tuple is deprecated." Use `data[tuple(pos.T)]` instead.